# Outputting message body from eZ Components ezcMailMultipartReport object

Tags: php, object, zeta-components

I'm attempting to output the message body of messages retrieved from my imap server, using the ezcMailImapTransport class from eZ Components.

I'm able to connect and retrieve all the messages, but I can't figure out how to output the message body.

The output of `print_r($mail[0]->body);` is below. I just don't know how to deal with an object like this.

The message itself is an email bounce notice.

```
ezcMailMultipartReport Object
(
    [parts:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => ezcMailText Object
                (
                    [headers:private] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
                        (
                            [lookup:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [content-description] => Content-Description
                                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                                )

                            [map:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [Content-Description] => Notification
                                    [Content-Type] => text/plain; charset=us-ascii
                                )

                        )

                    [headerCharsets:private] => Array
                        (
                            [Content-Description] => us-ascii
                            [Content-Type] => us-ascii
                        )

                    [excludeHeaders:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [properties:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => This is the mail system at host example.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for
    name=lskjsdf.com type=A: Host not found

                            [charset] => utf-8
                            [encoding] => 8bit
                            [subType] => plain
                            [originalCharset] => us-ascii
                            [size] => 501
                        )

                )

            [1] => ezcMailDeliveryStatus Object
                (
                    [headers:private] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
                        (
                            [lookup:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [map:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [headerCharsets:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [excludeHeaders:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [properties:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [message] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
                                (
                                    [lookup:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [reporting-mta] => Reporting-MTA
                                            [x-postfix-queue-id] => X-Postfix-Queue-ID
                                            [x-postfix-sender] => X-Postfix-Sender
                                            [arrival-date] => Arrival-Date
                                        )

                                    [map:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Reporting-MTA] => dns; example.com
                                            [X-Postfix-Queue-ID] => 78A6E92D38
                                            [X-Postfix-Sender] => rfc822; bounce@bounce.example.com
                                            [Arrival-Date] => Fri, 12 Jun 2009 17:43:07 -0400 (EDT)
                                        )

                                )

                            [recipients] => ArrayObject Object
                                (
                                    [0] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
                                        (
                                            [lookup:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [final-recipient] => Final-Recipient
                                                    [original-recipient] => Original-Recipient
                                                    [action] => Action
                                                    [status] => Status
                                                    [diagnostic-code] => Diagnostic-Code
                                                )

                                            [map:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Final-Recipient] => rfc822; kjdskfj@lskjsdf.com
                                                    [Original-Recipient] => rfc822;kjdskfj@lskjsdf.com
                                                    [Action] => failed
                                                    [Status] => 5.4.4
                                                    [Diagnostic-Code] => X-Postfix; Host or domain name not found. Name service error    for name=lskjsdf.com type=A: Host not found

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [size] => 431
                        )

                )

            [2] => ezcMailRfc822Digest Object
                (
                    [headers:private] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
                        (
                            [lookup:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                                    [content-disposition] => Content-Disposition
                                )

                            [map:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [Content-Type] => message/rfc822
                                    [Content-Disposition] => inline
                                )

                        )

                    [headerCharsets:private] => Array
                        (
                            [Content-Type] => us-ascii
                            [Content-Disposition] => us-ascii
                        )

                    [excludeHeaders:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [properties:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [mail] => ezcMail Object
                                (
                                    [headers:private] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
                                        (
                                            [lookup:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [received] => Received
                                                    [dkim-signature] => DKIM-Signature
                                                    [domainkey-signature] => DomainKey-Signature
                                                    [from] => From
                                                    [to] => To
                                                    [subject] => Subject
                                                    [mime-version] => MIME-Version
                                                    [user-agent] => User-Agent
                                                    [date] => Date
                                                    [message-id] => Message-Id
                                                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                                                    [content-transfer-encoding] => Content-Transfer-Encoding
                                                )

                                            [map:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Received] => from localhost (example.com [127.0.0.1]) by example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 51C3192D2A for ; Fri, 12 Jun 2009 17:43:07 -0400 (EDT)
                                                    [DKIM-Signature] => v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; d=example.com; h=from:to :subject:mime-version:date:message-id:content-type :content-transfer-encoding; s=qs762.1; bh=o1jS7VG7S60y5SvP5lioDm 5B7VY=; b=Bojv0GjNWsHTRyiKZ631bvWczjntEJZsegrsU2tt/1EI4KVQnRXmT+ u4oX6cQTpPK2xxZfiZ3BymPsoOD3weKSFmdwDOEUB4vEDdG+Bx697345c+KaSpdw IlJh2o3x0Zus/Ov8xRelHX+/6sklnN1GDllEQV2JlcKdKxR+fUrOQ=
                                                    [DomainKey-Signature] => a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; d=example.com; h=from:to :subject:mime-version:date:message-id:content-type :content-transfer-encoding; q=dns; s=qs762.1; b=HHzMU01/vNx4dBL5 OKyfxQzKytIIJB4KGhKWfFpSdsNNMPwCjrnRthz0wR4wqSgMIDmGobYOLujHekwM 1lLOAnMEQrXRWYHaIHBNIIrxemq1btuiMe8zNKEG3X/wSmYQE3xzInwPurB9iLAa Rjie7bJgTk0Tg+x54hav6l464Ok=
                                                    [From] => Example From
                                                    [To] => Ian Cook 
                                                    [Subject] => ezmail test 14:43:07
                                                    [MIME-Version] => 1.0
                                                    [User-Agent] => eZ Components
                                                    [Date] => Fri, 12 Jun 2009 14:43:07 -0700
                                                    [Message-Id] => <2009061214141207.76354.0@example.com>
                                                    [Content-Type] => text/plain; charset=us-ascii
                                                    [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => quoted-printable
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [headerCharsets:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Received] => us-ascii
                                            [DKIM-Signature] => us-ascii
                                            [DomainKey-Signature] => us-ascii
                                            [From] => us-ascii
                                            [To] => us-ascii
                                            [Subject] => us-ascii
                                            [MIME-Version] => us-ascii
                                            [User-Agent] => us-ascii
                                            [Date] => us-ascii
                                            [Message-Id] => us-ascii
                                            [Content-Type] => us-ascii
                                            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => us-ascii
                                        )

                                    [excludeHeaders:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [properties:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [from] => ezcMailAddress Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Example From
                                                    [email] => example@example.com
                                                    [charset] => utf-8
                                                )

                                            [to] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => ezcMailAddress Object
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => Ian Cook
                                                            [email] => kjdskfj@lskjsdf.com
                                                            [charset] => utf-8
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [cc] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [bcc] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [subject] => ezmail test 14:43:07
                                            [subjectCharset] => utf-8
                                            [body] => ezcMailText Object
                                                (
                                                    [headers:private] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
                                                        (
                                                            [lookup:private] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                                                                    [content-transfer-encoding] => Content-Transfer-Encoding
                                                                )

                                                            [map:private] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [Content-Type] => text/plain; charset=us-ascii
                                                                    [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => quoted-printable
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [headerCharsets:private] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Content-Type] => us-ascii
                                                            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => us-ascii
                                                        )

                                                    [excludeHeaders:private] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [properties:protected] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [text] => Test mail sent at 14:43:07

                                                            [charset] => utf-8
                                                            [encoding] => 8bit
                                                            [subType] => plain
                                                            [originalCharset] => us-ascii
                                                            [size] => 27
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [messageId] => <2009061214141207.76354.0@example.com>
                                            [returnPath] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [size] => 1473
                        )

                )

        )

    [headers:private] => ezcMailHeadersHolder Object
        (
            [lookup:private] => Array
                (
                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                )

            [map:private] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Type] => multipart/report; boundary="78A6E92D38.1244842987/example.com"
                )

        )

    [headerCharsets:private] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => us-ascii
        )

    [excludeHeaders:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [properties:protected] => Array
        (
            [noMimeMessage] => This message is in MIME format. Since your mail reader does not understand
this format, some or all of this message may not be legible.
            [boundary] => 78A6E92D38.1244842987/example.com
            [reportType] => delivery-status
            [size] => 2405
        )

)
```

Comment: Putting the entire dump of a variable is just lazy. People do not care about all that as it does not help, and in fact simply hinders any help they may offer.  Please ensure your question is in future reduced to a minimum of information that must be examined to aid other people in aiding you.

Comment: I put the whole dump so I could give everyone exact information about the object I was dealing with. I don't know how to handle the object, so I don't know what a person would need to know to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the EzComponents, but have you looked at http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/trunk/Mail/ezcMailMultipartReport.html#getParts to do something like:

```
$parts = $mail->getParts();
print_r($parts);  // or
print_r($parts[0]->body);  // (untested)
```

ezcMailMultipartReport is just a sub-class of ezcMailMultipart, and so all the actions that can take (or it's own parent, ezcMailPart), are available.

Comment: Thanks, this did it...

    $part = $mail[$i]->body->getParts();
    print_r($part[0]->text);